# Android: Make list navigation callback fire on selection of the same list item

Tags: java, android

I am currently using a list menu in my action bar with code as follows:

```
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
        list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
 // When menu item is selected and is different from currently selected menu item
}
```

Right now the callback is only fired if the menu item selected is different from the currently selected item. How can I make it fire even if the newly selected menu item is the same?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do, though? I had the same problem recently, but concluded that navigating in this fashion doesn't make sense. That is, if you are already on screen X, you don't need to navigate there. If you are not on screen X, it should not say 'X' in the ActionBar navigation list.